# Is there a reason to use folding bellows instead of my bag bellows for a range of lenses?

Tags: film, large-format, bellows

I have a 4x5 monorail camera and a range of lenses from 75mm to 210mm. I have normal folding bellows, and bag bellows, the latter is necessary for the wide angle lens.

However, the bag bellows has at least 30 cm of extension so I can use it with the 210mm as well. Is there any reason to carry the folding bellows into the field?

Answer (score 4):

Only if you prefer the ease of use with folding bellows as compared to bag bellows.

Bag bellows can be prone to sag in a way that partially blocks some of the light from the lens. Depending on the type and number of movements used, it may not always be obvious from just a cursory look if part of the bag is in the light path or not.

They're also fussier to get to store correctly in a camera, such as the Sinar P2, where the front and rear standards latch together for transport. Since you haven't indicated what type of 4X5 monorail camera you have, we have no way of knowing if yours is or isn't such a camera. Of course if you have two sets of bellows with you in the field, at least one of them will be detached from the camera during transport.